# “Gegenteil” with “von”, “zu” or genetive

Tags: preposition, genitive

I thought making an [Anki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki_(software)) deck for antonyms would be a pretty good idea. But I haven’t really learned the genitive case yet. I wanted to set the cards up like so:

> What's the antonym of {{Word 1}}?
>
> ---
>
> {{Word 2}}

And a reversed version of course.

I typed in a few example cases into google translate to see what it would translate into German as. The sentence “What is the antonym of ...” used a few different constructions depending on what word I put at the end:

- zu + word
- von + word
- definite article in genitive + word

So my questions are:

- What would I say in a case where the word hasn’t been decided yet?
- How would I determine which construction to use?

Comment: You wouldn’t use genitive at all with _Gegenteil_, whether you know the gender of the word or not.

Comment: I edited your question according to my understanding (we would not call a prepositional construction *genetive).* Please check whether everything is still according to your intentions.

Comment: *Was ist das Gegenteil von <Wort>* does the trick.

Comment: Oder "Was ist das Antonym zu Wort"

Comment: Thank you, I guess I wrongly assumed that the word of always signified the genitive case. But in this sentence, how would I know when to use zu, or when to use von?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Gegenteil **von** "gut" ist "gut gemeint".

**Von** is the one and only preposition for *Gegenteil*. 
**Zu** would fit to *Gegensatz* or *Widerspruch*. 
Maybe some people confuse that.

In addition, we have *Gegenteil*+genitive, especially when comparing someone or something with an abstract ideal: "*Du bist das Gegenteil eines Musterschülers*", "*Die letzte Woche war das Gegenteil eines Erholungsurlaubs"*. Often, this is emphasized with "*das genaue Gegenteil*". Using **von** here would spoil the lofty style.